# Strange Node.JS error

Tags: ipad, node.js, express

I have running in my Mac a **Node.JS** server, and, I access to it from other computer, the server doesn't crash, but, I don't know why, the application crashes when I access from my iPad. If I access from Safari, the server works, but, with Chrome for iPad, the app crash!

This is the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'following' of null`. Why this happens?

EDITED:

```
app.get('/home', middleware.yeses, function (req, res){

 console.log(req.session.user + "\n\n");

 UserModel.find({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

      console.log(user);

      res.render('home.ejs', {

         username: req.session.user,
         avatar: user[0].avatar,            
         following: user[0].following.length,
         followers: user[0].followers.length

      }); 

  });

});
```

EDITED:

I changed the `console.log(user);` to this `console.log(user[0].following)`. And there's no problem. I don't know why, there's a problem with it in the locals.

Comment: You're going to have to post the relevant code.

Comment: you are trying to read to property 'following' of some object somewhere, but the object has no valid value (is null). post your code

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which part of the code is the relevant! I have a lot of code, and the node.js server crash in the post and get request. And in other devices this error doesn't happen!

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the JavaScript is throwing an exception. Somewhere in the code, the there is a variable that is assigned to `null` and the property `following` is being  accessed on that variable.  This operation raises an exception.

```
var obj = null;
obj.following; // exception thrown!
```

It's impossible to help you more. With the info and code you've provided (very little of either). But look for where you are accessing a `following` property and debug from there.

---

**Update:**

It appears `user[0]` is `null`. Why? No idea. That depends on other code you haven't posted. WHere is `user` declared and populated? Is it an array? Because that would be strange for a variable named `user`.

Comment: But this is weird. This only happend in Chrome! In my mac I don't have this error. And in those part of the code is where the exception is called.

Comment: There is nothing inherently different about browsers that would cause this. Perhaps you have some browser platform detection that isn't setting things up right if it detects an iPad. It's hard to know without knowing what you app is and how it works.

Comment: If `user[0]` was null wouldn't the error occur earlier at `avatar: user[0].avatar`

Comment: @Musa you would think... Perhaps it's being thrown in the view then?

Comment: `UserModel.find({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user)` user is the result of this, a search of data with mongoose.

Comment: I was changing things and, basically, the problem is `user[0]` is null when I try to access to it property `following`, and i don't know why, because, I can show it in the console. And this only happens in Chrome for tablets and phones, I was trying it.